# And, yet, another evaluation to Catalan numbers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, enumerative-combinatorics

Construct the $n$-tuple Cartesian product of the ternary set $X_n=\{0,1,2\}\times\cdots\times\{0,1,2\}=\{0,1,2\}^n$. Define its subset $W_n$ according to the rule (here $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ is made use of)
$$W_n=\{y\in X_n: y_1\leq1, y_1+y_2\leq2,\dots,y_1+\cdots+y_{n-1}\leq n-1, y_1+\cdots+y_n=n\}.$$
Introduce the one-variable polynomial
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{y\in W_n}x^{\prod_{j=1}^n\binom{2}{y_j}}.$$

> **QUESTION.** If $C_n$ stands for the Catalan numbers, is this true?
> $$\frac{dP_n}{dx}(1)=C_{n+1}.$$

**Examples.** $P_1(x)=x^2, P_2(x)=x^4+x, P_3(x)=x^8+3x^2, P_4(x)=x^{16}+6x^4+2x$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

Write each $y_j = 1 - x_j$ with $x_j \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$,
so the condition is that $\sum_{j=1}^n x_n = 0$
and no partial sum is negative.
This can be viewed as an n-move king path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,0)$
that never goes below the horizontal axis.
We want the sum over such $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $2^h$
where $h$ is the number of indices $j$ for which $y_j = 1$, i.e. $x_j = 0$
(the number of horizontal king steps).

If we drop the nonnegativity condition, then for each $k$
the sum of $2^h$ over paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ is
the $t^k$ cofficient in the generating function $(t^{-1} + 2 + t)^n$;
since that's just $(t+1)^{2n} / t^n$, the sum is $2n \choose n+k$.

By a reflection argument familiar from the Catalan enumeration of Dyck paths,
it follows that for $k=0$ restricted to nonnegative paths
is the difference between the unrestricted $k=0$ and $k=-1$ sums,
which is ${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-2} = C_{n+1}$.

Comment: Alternatively we can reduce to Dyck paths of length $2(n+1)$:
the first step must be $\nearrow$, the last must be $\searrow$, 
and the 2n intermediate steps are grouped in pairs to get $n$ steps 
each of which is a double $\nearrow$, double $\searrow$, 
or (*with multiplicity $2$*) double $\rightarrow$, etc.

Comment: This is great. I was expecting $C_{n+1}$, not $C_n$. Is something missing?

Comment: You're right; I'll correct this.  The reflection argument gives
${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-2}$, not ${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-1}$.
I recognized ${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-1}$ as a Catalan number,
but didn't check that it's the correct one, and didn't notice that
I'm reflecting about the line $y = -1$, not $y = -1/2$.  
I don't think I ever knew or noticed that ${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-2}$
is a Catalan number too!
[It makes sense that it should be about $4$ times as large, because
${2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-m} \sim C_n m^2$ for small $m$ and large $n$.]

Comment: That's quite remarkable that $\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n-2}$ is also a Catalan number - I did not know it either!